# Weird behaviour of Thread.Sleep & Task.Delay

Tags: c#, runtime-error, beep

I started to develop a simple console metronome and I noticed that something gone wrong with the timing between beats.

After I set the tempo and start the metronome the beeps is working properly for a while and then it break the monotone rhythm and start to play the beep sound inaccurately with a strange rhythm.

Furthermore the duration of beep sound start to be shorter (cut it), along the tempo increasing.

---

I always got the error after a few second at 200 ms, so just test it at this tempo, but when you decrease it (mean increase the break between beeps), the issue will come later and later until it's totally disappear (about at 7-800 ms).

By the way, it doesn't matter what method I use (Sleep or Delay)...

---

Here a very simplified code which contain the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Temporary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Beep(2000, 200);
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                //Task.Delay(200).Wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what is this error and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` or `Task.Delay()` are not  accurate if you to get metronome like sound you should use something more accurate like (Multimedia Timers)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Multimedia/about-multimedia-timers]

Comment: Doubtful anybody would get a easy repro.  Thread.Sleep() and Task.Delay() use the exact same underlying OS resource.  There is no service guarantee, the OS considers everything else that ask for service as well.  The kind that plays havoc on most programmer's machines when they make an executable file appear from nowhere is anti-malware.  Temporarily disable it to see if that makes a difference.  If not and you see no obvious activity in Task Manager then changing the Thread.Priority is not inappropriate.

Comment: @styx: Though `Thread.Sleep` can be inaccurate for very tight delays (shorter than 15ms) it is actually quite precise for >50 ms ranges. Here must be some other problem. @BushWookie: For myself I could not reproduce it on my 8 core computer even with decreasing the delays to 50ms. Do you execute it without the debugger attached?

Comment: @taffer: Yes, it perhaps something else than accuracy issue, but I have no idea what... I tried to run without debugging and standalone as well, but the problem still there.

Comment: @styx: I'm a beginner yet and the Multimedia Timers looks like quite complex on my level. I try to learn it maybe it will fix the problem but it's difficult, but thanks!

Comment: @Hans Passant: I don't know how Thread.Priority can help me, but I try to figure it out.